# getting 302 code when Invoking Jenkins job remote trigger

Tags: jenkins

I am intermittently getting a **302** response when I try to trigger a job on a remote Jenkins server, we are not able to rely on this trigger because when we get the 302 code the job is not triggered

I tried using the `curl -L` but it didn't help, the same result with `wget` as well.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this issue today, our problem turned out to be a firewall between the two servers. We investigated the issue using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), the clue was in the `location` header in the `302` response.